# std::reference_wrapper around *this

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a scenario where I need to convert a function that can be chained by `*this` to returning `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` instead of `T&` (reason is out of scope for this question). The reason why I use `std::reference_wrapper` is since `std::optional` cannot take a reference, at least not in C++11. However, that doesn't work because I seem to be encountering lifetime issues. Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct test {
    std::reference_wrapper<test> foo() {
        val = 42;
        return *this;
    }

    test& foo2() {
        val = 50;
        return *this;
    }

    int val;
};

void bar(test t) {
    std::cout << std::move(t).val << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    auto f = test().foo();
    bar(f);
    auto g = test().foo2();
    bar(g);
}
```

This outputs `0 50` instead of the expected `42 50`. If I split it up into two statements:

```
auto f = test();
auto f2 = f.foo();
bar(f2);
```

It works as expected. Using the debugger, I discover that the compiler is optimizing some of the expression away and `val` is left uninitialized, which leads me to think I have undefined behavior in my code.

Do I have undefined behavior? If so, how do I avoid it here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I have undefined behavior?

Yes. `auto` deduces the type of the object from the expression used to initialize it. And you use an expression of type `std::reference_wrapper<test>` to initialize `f`. The temporary `test()` is gone after `f` is initialized, so `f` dangles immediately.

You can either split the declaration as you do already, or use `std::references_wrappers`'s get member function:

```
auto f = test().foo().get();
```

Either way, `std::reference_wrapper<test>` is not a drop in replacement for a reference in all contexts C++ supports. Proxy objects never are.

Comment: It's worse.  See my answer too.

Comment: No. It isn't - g is of type `test` - that's the way `auto` works.  Wrong answer deleted.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I have undefined behavior?

Yes. Have a look at the line `auto f = test().foo();`. `f` is a `std::reference_wrapper<test>` and the `test` instance it refers to is `test()`. The lifetime of `test()` ends right at the end of this line, and you end up with a dangling reference. That's not the case for `auto g = test().foo2();` as it copies the return value (thanks to @StoryTeller for helping me out here).

> how do I avoid it here?

You need to tear apart lifetime management from the `std::reference_wrapper` part. This will work:

```
test t;
auto f = t.foo();

// Do stuff with f until this scope ends.
```

Comment: "Same issue for `auto g = test().foo2();`" - No. `g` is copy initialized from the reference to the still living temporary.